# How can you output HTML depending on the width of browser windows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made this javascript and tried but never works.
It has to show advertising banner.
If I put this iframe on out side of javascript tag, it works fine but I did put inside of javascript tag because iframe will be decided depending one the width of browser window.

How can I make this work????

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    width = jQuery(".pagenator").width();
    if (width > 730) {
        <iframe frameborder='0' allowtransparency='true' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' scrolling='no' width='728' height='90' src='http://foofoofoofootest.com/adspot.aspx?id=21442?'>
        </iframe>
    } else if (width > 470) {
        <iframe frameborder='0' allowtransparency='true' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' scrolling='no' width='468' height='60' src='http://foofoofoofootest.com/adspot.aspx?id=21443?'>
        </iframe>
    } else if (width > 255) {
        <iframe frameborder='0' allowtransparency='true' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' scrolling='no' width='250' height='250' src='http://foofoofoofootest.com/adspot.aspx?id=21444?'>
        </iframe>
    } else {
        <iframe frameborder='0' allowtransparency='true' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' scrolling='no' width='200' height='200' src='http://foofoofoofootest.com/adspot.aspx?id=21445?'>
        </iframe>
    }       
</script>   


<head>

<body>



</body>

</html>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var TheHTML = "";
    width = jQuery(".pagenator").width();
    if (width > 730) {
        TheHTML = "<iframe frameborder='0' allowtransparency='true' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' scrolling='no' width='728' height='90' src='http://foofoofoofootest.com/adspot.aspx?id=21442'></iframe>";
    } else if (width > 470) {
        TheHTML = "<iframe frameborder='0' allowtransparency='true' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' scrolling='no' width='468' height='60' src='http://foofoofoofootest.com/adspot.aspx?id=21443'></iframe>";
    } else if (width > 255) {
        TheHTML = "<iframe frameborder='0' allowtransparency='true' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' scrolling='no' width='250' height='250' src='http://foofoofoofootest.com/adspot.aspx?id=21444'></iframe>";
    } else {
        TheHTML = "<iframe frameborder='0' allowtransparency='true' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' scrolling='no' width='200' height='200' src='http://foofoofoofootest.com/adspot.aspx?id=21445'></iframe>";
    }
    $("#frameHolder").html(TheHTML);        
</script>           


<div id="frameHolder"></div>


</body>
```

Comment: why don't you just use `media queries` and `display: none;` and then `display: block;`. You don't need to use `JS` for something that can be done with `CSS`

Comment: do a console.log() on your width variable and see what is in there, I would guess that it returns a string.

Comment: I think you need to push be pushing this logic into the iframe's source rather than the holder for the content. Then use media quieries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[check out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9PsUU/)

```
This should help you figure out what you need to do.
```

Comment: Thanks that was it!!! I had <div> part below the javascript!! You made me noticed thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the HTML to the DOM; like this:

```
var TheHTML = "";
var width = jQuery(".pagenator").width(); // add a var, otherwise you're creating a global
if (width > 730) {
     TheHTML = "<iframe frameborder='0' allowtransparency='true' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' scrolling='no' width='728' height='90' src='http://foofoofoofootest.com/adspot.aspx?id=21442?'></iframe>";
} else if (width > 470) { ....

$('ContainerOfTheIframe').html(TheHTML);
```

This should work. Also make sure you have jQuery available when the script runs (ie. put the reference for the jquery.js file above your script).

Comment: Thanks. Can you outout the result of TheHTML to right before </body>? If so, how?

Comment: It seems your code output the result to the element that has name 'ContainerOfTheIframe' as ID?

Comment: You need to put the iframe into something. I would go to the DOM and add an empty div where you want the iframe to go, and give this div an ID. Then put this ID in place of $('ContainerOfTheIframe')

Comment: $("body").append(theHtml)

Comment: @frenchie Thanks what would you recommend? something like this?'<span id="ContainerOfTheIframe"></span>'

Comment: probably better to use a div there.

Comment: <div id="frameHolder"></div>
$("#frameHolder").append(theHtml);

Comment: you can add the <div> before the closing </body>

Comment: so should it be something like this? '<div id="frameHolder"></div> $("#frameHolder").append(TheHtml)</body>;'

Comment: If you want to add the iframe before the closing </body> then just add this: <div id="TheIframe"></div></body> to the DOM and then in the javascript just change this: $('#TheIframe').html(TheHTML); Note that you can also use .append() but I prefer adding an empty div so that a person working with the HTML source will see the empty tag in the HTML.

Comment: @frenchie Thanks. I tried it. But it's so weird that it won't show the ad:( if I just paste '<iframe>...' directly to inside of <body> that shows fine:(

Comment: @frenchie please check my UPDATE. Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var pagewidth = jQuery(".pagenator").width(),
pageId = 0;
  if (pagewidth > 730) {
  pageId = 21442;
} 
else if (pagewidth > 470) {
  pageId = 21443;
}
else if (pagewidth > 255) {
  pageId = 21444;
}
else {
  pageId = 21445;
}    
$('body').html("<iframe frameborder='0' allowtransparency='true' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' scrolling='no' width='728' height='90' src='http://foofoofoofootest.com/adspot.aspx?id='" + pageId + "'?'></iframe>");
```